# How generate a reference label from a non-floating figure?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have a figure that I don't want to float, i.e. I generate it with

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=80mm]{figure_file}
\end{center}

\stepcounter{figure}
Figure~\arabic{figure}. \label{fig:A}
Caption text here.

As shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:A}, this does not work!
```

However, the `\label{}` command does, of course, not generate the desired reference marker. My question: how can I force this?

Comment: Change `\stepcounter` to `\refstepcounter` and then put label after that command. It will work then.

Comment: This kind of question pops up occasionally. It is apparently not really obvious that the reference `\ref` macro and `\refstepcounter` are closely related ;-)

Comment: @TeXnician Please provide your comment as answer and I'll happily accept.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If this is so, please close as duplicate with an appropriate well-asked and well-answered question.

Comment: @Walter: It was closed already for about 16 hours at the time you wrote your comment ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I see this now, but when I typed the comment, this was not apparent. Perhaps I should have refreshed the page?